# How i can isolate all design elements in Flutter to one ThemeData class ... Have any strategy os solution?

Tags: flutter, dart

How i can isolate all design elements in Flutter to one ThemeData class file. Colors,Decoraion, colors scheme. I try to separete my code to Design, page, busines/ some one like...

myThemeData file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTheme {
  final BuildContext context;

  MyTheme({this.context});

  ColorScheme get myColorSheme {
    return Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
          primary: Colors.red,
          onPrimary: Colors.black,
          primaryVariant: Colors.orange,
          background: Colors.red,
          onBackground: Colors.black,
          secondary: Colors.red,
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          secondaryVariant: Colors.deepOrange,
          error: Colors.black,
          onError: Colors.white,
          surface: Colors.white,
          onSurface: Colors.black,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
        );
  }

  ThemeData get myThemeData {
    return ThemeData(
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
      ),
      hintColor: Colors.red,
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      colorScheme: myColorSheme,
    );
  }

  static InputDecoration inputDecoration({String hintText, Icon icon}) {
    return InputDecoration(
      hintStyle: MyTheme.hintTextStyle,
      hintText: hintText,
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white54, width: 1),
      ),
      prefixIcon:
          IconTheme(data: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white), child: icon),
    );
  }

  static TextStyle get hintTextStyle {
    return TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white30);
  }

  static TextStyle get textFieldStyle {
    return TextStyle();
  }

  static TextStyle get logoTextStyle {
    return TextStyle(
      fontSize: 40,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    );
  }
}
```

as result I have error

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#84f70):
Assertion failed:
C:\…\material\theme_data.dart:316
colorScheme?.brightness == null || brightness == null || colorScheme!.brightness == brightness
is not true

The relevant error-causing widget was
MyApp
lib\main.dart:10
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw*
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3    assertFailed
packages/flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart 316:106                                                                      new
packages/services/UI/Theme.dart 27:12                                                                                      get myThemeData
packages/services/main.dart 24:38                                                                                          build
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to use `copyWith` method while defining your own theme Data. Most of the times use don't use all the fields and some field are compulsory.

So do something like this

```
For Dark theme
 ThemeData get myThemeData {
    return ThemeData.dark().copyWith()(
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
      ),
      hintColor: Colors.red,
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      colorScheme: myColorSheme,
    );
  }


For Light theme
 ThemeData get myThemeData {
    return ThemeData.light().copyWith()(
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
      ),
      hintColor: Colors.red,
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      colorScheme: myColorSheme,
    );
  }
```

You can also see how  i have used the ThemeData in one of my project see below

My Dark/Black Theme

```
ThemeData blackTheme(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    snackBarTheme: SnackBarThemeData(
      backgroundColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
      actionTextColor: greyColor,
      contentTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      shape: const ContinuousRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    accentColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
    cardColor: Colors.black,
    primaryColor: Colors.black,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColorLight: Colors.black,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
    dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
    canvasColor: Colors.black,
    floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      backgroundColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
    ),
    dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
    textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
      cursorColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
      selectionHandleColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
      selectionColor: darken(selectedPrimaryColor, 50),
    ),
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      headline5: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      headline1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      headline2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      subtitle2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }
            return selectedPrimaryColor; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
        /* elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<double>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return 0;
            }
            return 0; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),*/
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }
            return selectedPrimaryColor; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    bottomSheetTheme: const BottomSheetThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    ),
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }
            return Colors.white; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }
            return Colors.black; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

My Light Theme

```
ThemeData lightTheme(BuildContext context) {
  // debugPrint(selectedPrimaryColor.toString());
  return ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    canvasColor: Colors.white,
    cardColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
    accentColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
    toggleableActiveColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
    primaryColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
    dialogTheme: const DialogTheme(
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    )),
    snackBarTheme: SnackBarThemeData(
      backgroundColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
      actionTextColor: Colors.white,
      contentTextStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      shape: const ContinuousRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline5: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      headline1: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      headline2: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      bodyText1: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      bodyText2: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      caption: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      subtitle1: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      subtitle2: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[200]),
    ),
    textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
      cursorColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
      selectionHandleColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
      selectionColor: lighten(selectedPrimaryColor, 65),
    ),
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }
            return selectedPrimaryColor; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return Colors.black;
            }
            return selectedPrimaryColor; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonTheme:
        Theme.of(context).floatingActionButtonTheme.copyWith(
              backgroundColor: selectedPrimaryColor,
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }
            return selectedPrimaryColor;
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thax. As I understand copyWith(...) is for partly change only  what you want?

Comment: Yes it is. But if you decide to go other path. Defining everything from scratch. Then you should provide all compulsory fields.

Comment: Kop kop rakhme (very very Thax)  P.S. Sory for my English!

Comment: If it posible? 1 mode question! How I undestand in MaterialApp have 2 mode Dakr and light! Can I create MyMode? And how it bette to reatisation?